# How to map a list of objects to an object that contains multiple lists?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using automapper 9.0.0.

My situation is as follows. I have a list of items which are all instances of an abstract base class, let's call it `BaseClass`. There are 2 classes that inherit that class, let's call those `Bar1Class` and `Bar2Class`.

I want to map a list of `BaseClass` to an object that contains 2 lists. One list is a DTO for the `Bar1Class` objects from the list, and the 2nd one is for the `Bar2Class` objects from the list:

```
List<BaseClass> items = GetItems();
var dto = Mapper.Map<FooResponseModel>(items);
```

The hierarchy is as follows:

```
// Response models
public class FooResponseModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Bar1Model> Bar1Models {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Bar2Model> Bar2Models {get;set;}
}

public class Bar1Model
{
    public string MyString {get;set;}
    public int MyInt {get;set;}
}

public class Bar2Model
{
    public string MyString {get;set;}
    public bool MyBool {get;set;}
}
```

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
   public string MyString {get;set;}
}

public class Bar1Class : BaseClass
{
   public int MyInt {get;set;}
}

public class Bar2Class : BaseClass
{
   public bool MyBool {get;set;}
}
```

How would I set this up?

Using the `CreateMap<BaseClass, FooResponseModel>()` doesn't really work because I can't divide the collections. Doing something like `CreateMap<Bar1Class, Bar1Model>()` would allow me to map the classes itself, but not allow me to set up the lists.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I would map it by hand like this now, because i dont know how to map the upper object correctly. I would of course add `CreateMap<Bar1Class, Bar1Model>()` and such beforehand.

```
var dto = new FooResponseModel
{
    Bar1Models = items
        .Where(x => x is Bar1Class)
        .Cast<Bar1Class>()
        .Select(x => Mapper.Map<Bar1Model>()),
    Bar2Models = items.
        .Where(x => x is Bar2Class)
        .Cast<Bar2Class>()
        .Select(x => Mapper.Map<Bar2Model>())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two maps between source classes and destination classes. Then, add mapping from a sequence of `BaseClass` to `FooResponseModel` and point AutoMapper how to populate `Bar1Models` and `Bar2Models` properties.

```cs
CreateMap<Bar1Class, Bar1Model>();
CreateMap<Bar2Class, Bar2Model>();
CreateMap<IEnumerable<BaseClass>, FooResponseModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Bar1Models, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Where(b => b is Bar1Class)))
    .ForMember(d => d.Bar2Models, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Where(b => b is Bar2Class)));
```